# Lauching a Python server from R in a background prompt

Tags: python, r, server

I have a script launching a server in `Python` (taking as argument a depo folder where a sqlite database is created and a port). I would like to call it from my RGui:

```
cmd = 'python c:\\scratch\\python\\python.exe c:\\scratch\\server.py c:\\scratch\\depo 8080'
res = system(command)

#.Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using RocketServer())...
#Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8086/
#Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

#2015-06-10 11:19:05,938 Starting Rocket 1.2.4
#2015-06-10 11:19:05,967 Listening on sockets: 0.0.0.0:8086
```

(the comments are messages displayed by bottle and rocket, libraries I used to create the server).

However my `Rgui` becomes unusable since the server is running in it. I would rather like to launch an instance of this server in a prompt running in a background but not in my `R` session ...

I would be grateful if someone has an idea!

Comment: What happened when you tried `wait=FALSE`? BTW: many recommend the use of `system2` over `system` or `shell`, citing portability and such. The options are similar, though you'll need to break the command up to "command" and "all other arguments". I haven't seen problems with one or the other, so it's only heresay, sorry.

Comment: This might also help: http://superuser.com/a/591084/147411

Comment: r2evans comment is great! Indeed the solution hides in the option ... but then I wonder how to get the pid of the process launched ...